# Hit Counter: Separate Date + Time Fields vs one DateTime2 field

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database, hitcounter

I am planning out a hit counter, and I plan to make many report queries to show number of hits total in a day, the past week, the past month, etc, as well as one that would feed a chart that shows what time of day was most popular, within a specific date range, for a specific page.

With this in mind, would it be beneficial to store the `DATE` in a separate field from the `TIME` that the hit occurred, then add indexes? I would be using a `where clause` with a range (greater than x and less than y) for some of these queries. I do expect to have queries that ask about both the `Date` and the `Time`, such as "within the past 6 months, show me number of hit grouped per hour of the day."

Am I over complicating it? should I just use a single `DateTime2(0)` field or is there some advantage to using two fields for this?

Comment: I would say go for a simple datetime. Although it may seem useful to keep two separate fields for this ultimately you will always want the days and time ranges where the most or least hits occur. As there are functions like DATEPART which helps break the date and time easily keeping date and time together in one column will make more sense.

Comment: DateTime is fine for all purposes. For specific hours of a day, you can use DATEPART as @Sam mentioned. To break down even further (e.g. half-hour chunks), you can use funky stuff like DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATE) % 1440 / 30, to break it down into 48 half-hour segments.

Comment: To date, I have not found a useful purpose for a Time field (in a table), that would be better served as a DateTime.  I suspect that you're too smart, and you're over-thinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are bordering [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) with this approach.

Use Datetime. In due time (i.e. after your application has reached Production and you have a better idea of the actual requirements and how it performs) you can for example introduce views to aggregate your data in a way that proves more useful for any reporting/querying you have to perform frequently.

In the most extreme case you can even refactor your schema and migrate everything from Datetime to two distinct fields, but I doubt this will prove necessary.

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, it does feel like a premature optimization. Thanks guys for saving me some unnecessary complications.